# Reading different types of data from a file

Tags: java, algorithm, file, loops

So for an assignment I have to take a file that looks like:

```
2141512   
Math
68

7493674
History
82

8403785
English
23

4213432
French
75

7556463
Science
97

2345215
ICS
49
```

The longer numbers are student numbers and the 2 digit numbers are the made up marks, I need a program that reads the file and creates 2 other documents. One to show the subject and mark of those how passed (pass.txt) and one to show who failed their class (fail.txt). So far I've go this, but I don't know If i should read it all as strings and convert the marks into integers, and I don't know how to read the lines as different data types.

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteKONG
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
     BufferedReader in;
     in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       String line;
       int i;

    PrintWriter fail;
    PrintWriter pass;
    fail = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fail.txt"));
    pass = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("pass.txt"));
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("marks.txt"));
    line = in.readLine();
    i = Integer.valueOf(line).intValue();
    while (line  != null);
    {
    if (line != "English" || line != "Math" || line != "Science" || line != "ICS" || line != "History" || line != "French")
        do { i = Integer.valueOf(line).intValue();
        pass.println();

         i = Integer.valueOf(line).intValue();
         while(line <= 50 || line < 101);
         i = Integer.valueOf(line).intValue();
         if (line >= 49 ){
         fail.println();
         }
         i = Integer.valueOf(line).intValue();
         if (line >= 50 || line < 101){
         pass.println();i = Integer.valueOf(line).intValue();

         }

     } 
       while (line != null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The scanner class in Java can do file reading and it has Double,int,string that it can read.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with its `next()` and `nextInt()` methods.

[Usage example](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~bvz/cs365/examples/datacheck.html) similiar to what you have.

Comment: @Ryan Well, that's not the best advice, since `BufferedReader` is more low-level, it can only read a single character or the whole line, which is not as convenient as `Scanner` in your case. Try it and you will see.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Its an homework, i guess he has no option there :P

Answer (score 0):

You are on right path for using Java File API, all you need to do is some tweaking to your code.

1. do not compare the strings with `==` instead use `line.equals("English")`
2. you need to replace all `||` in first if with `&&`
3. you need to use `Integer.parseInt(line)`
4. you need to remove `;` after every while statement. (otherwise these are infinite loops)

I hope this can help, try to debug your logic.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(line)` is same as `Integer.valueOf(line).intValue();`